# Button to refresh page every second/minute etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting a button that when clicked will refresh the current page after a specified amount of time.

I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function reload(){
    location = ''
  },1000)
</script>

<button onclick="reload()">Reload</button>
```

However, that JUST reloads the page without even having to click the button. I'm wanting the button to execute the script, and also a button to STOP the page reload.

This should be really simple but I can't figure it out :(

********EDIT************

I'd also like the script to run on an infinite loop after the button is clicked.

Comment: Put your "setTimeout" in a function. And call that function from button.

Answer (score 6):

Your `setTimeout` is called on page load. You need to put it inside the `reload()` function:

```
function reload() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 1000);
}
```

To make the timer run every x seconds and reload only a part of the page you would need to use `setInterval` and an AJAX request, something like this:

```
var timer;
function reload() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $.post('foo.html', function(data) {
            $('#bar').html(data);
        });
    }, 1000);
}

function clear() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, that worked just fine for what I asked. I did, however, forget to mention that I'd like the script to run on a infinite loop after the button is clicked, sorry.

Comment: @LukeJennings That won't be possible as you are reloading the page, so it will be set back to it's initial state. To do what you need you would need to use AJAX to refresh only a part of the page every X seconds.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for the code there is no need to clear the timeout as the page is reloaded :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What if I were to reload the contents of an iframe? Could I create a button that reloads the iframe on a loop?

Comment: @Andrex thanks, put the timer in and forgot the AJAX example :)

Comment: @LukeJennings that would work too, although it's a little ugly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, I'm struggling to put that into practice (reloading the source of the iframe only), can you assist?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reload(){
    setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 3000);
  }
</script>

<button onclick="reload()">Reload</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is

```
window.setTimeout("location = ''"; ,1000);
```

You were saying execute this function after 1 second. You need to define the setTimeout inside the function. Also there is a built in method to reload the page. Call that instead of setting the location to a blank string.

```
function reload() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    },1000);
}
```

Now to cancel the timeout, you need to use `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`; You get the timeoutId from the integer that the setTimeout returns when you call it.

```
var timer = null;
function reload() {
    timer = window.setTimeout( function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    },1000);
}

function cancelReload() {
    if (timer)  {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = null;
}
```

AND you said you want it to keep running. That will require cookies or localstorage.

```
var timer = null;
function reload() {
    localStorage.reload = true;  //set localstorage so we know to fire it off again
    timer = window.setTimeout( function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    },1000);
}

function cancelReload() {
    if (timer)  {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = null;
   localStorage.removeItem("reload");  //remove the key in localstorage
}

if (localstorage.reload) {  //check localstorage to see if key is set
    reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole thing in another function and call that from the button click